# Why does GCC show duplicate warnings for bad printf format specifier?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, clang

I'm curious why GCC shows me *two* identical warnings when compiling this file:

```
$ cat test.c 
#include <stdio.h> 

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    long foo = 0l;
    printf("%i\n", foo);

    return 0;
}
$ gcc-4.2 -Wall test.c 
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:6: warning: format ‘%i’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’
test.c:6: warning: format ‘%i’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’
```

Interestingly, Clang also gives two warnings:

```
$ clang test.c 
test.c:6:14: warning: conversion specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'long' [-Wformat]
    printf("%i\n", foo);
            ~^     ~~~
            %ld
test.c:6:14: warning: conversion specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'long' [-Wformat]
    printf("%i\n", foo);
            ~^     ~~~
            %ld
2 warnings generated.
```

Any ideas?

---

For info:

```
$ gcc-4.2 -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Configured with: /private/var/tmp/gcc/gcc-5666.3~278/src/configure
--disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/usr --mandir=/share/man
--enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++
--program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib
--build=i686-apple-darwin11 --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11-
--host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11
--with-gxx-include-dir=/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)

$ clang -v
Apple clang version 2.1 (tags/Apple/clang-163.7.1) (based on LLVM 3.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

---

EDIT: the 'multi-architecture' hypothesis a few have suggested sounded good, but I'm not sure it's right. If I force a single architecture with `-arch`, I get two warnings. If I specify `-arch x86_64 -arch i386`, I get two sets of duplicate warnings!

```
$ gcc-4.2 -Wall -arch x86_64 test.c 
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:6: warning: format ‘%i’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’
test.c:6: warning: format ‘%i’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’

$ gcc-4.2 -Wall -arch x86_64 -arch i386 test.c 
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:6: warning: format ‘%i’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’
test.c:6: warning: format ‘%i’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:6: warning: format ‘%i’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’
test.c:6: warning: format ‘%i’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’
```

---

EDIT: I don't get dupes for all warning types. `-Wformat` is the only one I've come across so far. For example, if I throw in an unused variable I only get one warning for that:

```
$ cat test.c 
#include <stdio.h> 

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    long foo = 0l;
    long bar;
    printf("%i\n", foo);

    return 0;
}

$ gcc-4.2 -Wall test.c 
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:7: warning: format ‘%i’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’
test.c:7: warning: format ‘%i’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’
test.c:6: warning: unused variable ‘bar’
```

Comment: FWIW, I only get one error message when I use GCC 4.1.2.  Are you sure this isn't an artifact of your build system, which is somehow invoking GCC twice?

Comment: Thanks Oli. I'm not sure at all, it probably is. :-/

Comment: I'm not seeing the duplicate warning. But then, it's a warning you should be fixing anyway, so...

Comment: I get a single warning with gcc 4.5.2 and clang 2.8, both on Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because Apple's `stdio.h` header attaches a [GCC `format` attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.4/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bformat_007d-function-attribute-1880) to its declaration of `printf()`...

(e.g. see the declaration of `printf()` [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-763.11/include/stdio.h) and the declaration of the `__printflike()` macro [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1228.15.4/bsd/sys/cdefs.h))

...but GCC (and Clang, due to it trying to be very GCC-compatible!) already has built-in knowledge that `printf()` is a function which takes `printf`-style arguments.  You're getting one warning due to the built-in knowledge, and a second warning due to the explicit attribute.

You can demonstrate the same behaviour on other platforms (with at least several versions of GCC) by doing the same thing yourself:

```
extern int printf(const char *, ...) __attribute__((__format__ (__printf__, 1, 2)));

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    long foo = 0l;
    printf("%i\n", foo);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Problem solved. (You can also demonstrate that this is the correct answer by removing the ` __DARWIN_LDBL_COMPAT(printf) __printflike(1, 2)` from the definition of `printf` in `/usr/include/stdio.h` then re-compiling.)

Answer (score 3):

If you're targetting two CPU architectures (ARMv6/ARMv7 on iOS, for instance, or i386/x86_64 on Mac), you'll see two copies of each warning because the compiler runs twice for each file (once for each architecture.)

On a Mac, you can get it up to 4 warnings per line if you enable PPC/PPC64 support. ;)

**Edit**: Matthew's got it spot-on in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're compiling for iOS. The code is being compiled multiple times for multiple architectures. The warning is being generating for each architecture.

Comment: The multi-architecture explanation makes sense, but not sure it's the case here. If I add e.g. `-arch x86_64` to my gcc or clang flags, I still get duplicate warnings. If I add `-arch x86_64 -arch i386`, I get four warnings. :)

Comment: -1: evidently he isn't compiling for iOS, nor doing s multi-arch build. The compiler invocation is specified in the question.